# When a user starts scrolling on a mobile device, can it be canceled with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When a user swipes a page on a mobile device and it starts scrolling with momentum, is it possible to cancel the scroll and its momentum with Javascript?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I hate it when pages try to override my scrolling. If you want to have "scroll stops" then use CSS for that instead of scripting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts

Comment: I want to use scripting because I'm using a JS library to detect swipes and I am binding a swipe on a div to close the div, but then I don't want the page to start scrolling as a result.

Comment: Like this? https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/prevent-scroll-on-scrollable-element-js/

Answer (score 1):

Add the style `overflow: hidden` to the container, and then remove it quickly. This will keep the scrolling position of the document, but stop all momentum.
(To cancel the scroll in this example, press any key, like `a`)

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "A very tall div<br/>".repeat(300)


document.addEventListener("keypress", ()=>{
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
  setTimeout(()=>
  document.body.style.overflow = "", 100)
})
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```